# Excel VBA: Checking to see if google drive shortcut exist

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to check if a shortcut through the user's Google Drive exists

```
path = "G:\My Drive\Templates\"
If len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then
    'folder or shortcut exists
```

This code will work if the path is a folder, but not if the path is a shortcut.

Any ideas how to resolve? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Retrieve Shortcut Properties](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=850335):

```vb
Sub test1()
    shk = "c:\temp\test.lnk"
    Set WshShortcut = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(shk)
    Path = WshShortcut.TargetPath
    If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print "Path `" & Path & "` exists"
    End If
End Sub
```